# VSC does not import installed python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, import

I recently got a new computer and installed VSC as well as the official python on it. I installed some extra libraries for python on it with pip but whenever I want to run a script it gives me the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy', or any other library installed afterwards. The libraries that come with python do work.

When I run the same script in IDLE for example, all the libraries are found and it works fine, but I would like to be able to code in VSC.

For example:

```
import numpy as np 
import pygame as pg
import time

Rest of the code...
```

The error occurs right when it tries to import the libraries.

Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Comment: It might be pointing to the wrong interpreter. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: It is working with the 32-bit interpreter now, so thanks a lot!